# Pushwoosh Remote API for cordova

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, pushwoosh

I want to send push notifications from the client (my cordova (ionic) app) through [pushwoosh](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/pushwoosh-push-notification-remote-api/).

Is there any sample code or guides for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the plugin for Phonegap https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin and the documentation on Pushwoosh site https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/.

Comment: I have succeeded to set up everything for cordova android, my device is receiving push notifications when I send it from pushwoosh.com. I can't find any sample code in the repository for the plugin for phonegap for **sending** push notifications from the client. Have I overlooked anything?

Comment: You can't push from the client. The client (device) can only register for receiving notifications.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the [Remote Access API](http://docs.pushwoosh.com/docs/createmessage) which requires a paid plan.
I create an object that contains the text I want to send and the device tokens I want to send it to and pass that as an argument to the following function:

```
function push(object) {
  var params = {
    "request": {
      "application": "PW_ID GOES HERE",
      "auth": "Find in your API Access page",
      "notifications": [{
        // Content Settings
        "send_date": "now",
        "ignore_user_timezone": true,
        "content": {
          "en": object.text
        },
        "platforms": [1, 3], // 1 - iOS; 3 - Android;
        // iOS Related
        "ios_category_id": "1",
        "ios_badges": "+1",
        // Android Related
        "android_icon": "icon",
        // Who to send it to
        "devices": object.tokens
      }]
    }
  };
  $http.post('https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/createMessage', params).then(success, failure);

  function success() {
    console.log("successful notification push");
  }

  function failure(error) {
    console.log('error sending notification', error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here is something like what i use

- send a request to a server

```js
$http.get('http://test.com/push.php?token=' + ushToken + '&message=' + encodeURIComponent(message)).then(function (resp) {
}, function (err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```

- on the server side do

```html
<?php

define('PW_AUTH', '...');
define('PW_APPLICATION', '...');
define('PW_DEBUG', FALSE);

function pwCall($method, $data)
{
 $url     = 'https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/' . $method;
 $request = json_encode(['request' => $data]);

 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);

 $response = curl_exec($ch);
 $info     = curl_getinfo($ch);
 curl_close($ch);

 if (defined('PW_DEBUG') && PW_DEBUG) {
  var_dump(json_decode($request));
  var_dump($response);
  var_dump($info);
 }
}

if (isset($_GET['message']) && isset($_GET['token'])) {
 $payload = [
  'application'   => PW_APPLICATION,
  'auth'          => PW_AUTH,
  'notifications' => [
   [
    'send_date' => 'now',
    'content'   => $_GET['message'],
    'devices'   => [$_GET['token']]
   ]
  ]
 ];

 pwCall('createMessage', $payload);
}
```